# How to render common things in footer.html in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have set up Django templates, which include `index.html`, `header.html` and `footer.html`.

In `footer.html`, I want to set dynamically a phone number, email and address. I can see I can pass it through `context` from `views.py`, but `footer.html` will included in all the templates, so I will need to pass it in every function in views.py, which is not good.

So what I want is to create one common function and I want to call it from `footer.html`. Is that the right way to do this? Or if you have any other idea, then please let me know how to do that.

*views.py*:

```
def index(request):
    portal_contact_email = preferences.MyPreferences.portal_contact_email
    context = {'portal_contact_email': portal_contact_email,}
    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', context)
```

*footer.html*:

```
<footer class="bg-dark footer-section">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h5 class="text-light">Email</h5>
          <p class="text-white paragraph-lg font-secondary">{{ portal_contact_email }} </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h5 class="text-light">Phone</h5>
          <p class="text-white paragraph-lg font-secondary"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h5 class="text-light">Address</h5>
          <p class="text-white paragraph-lg font-secondary"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border-top text-center border-dark py-5">
    <p class="mb-0 text-light">Copyright @<script>
        var CurrentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
        document.write(CurrentYear)
      </script>
{#        a theme by <a href="https://themefisher.com">themefisher.com</a>#}
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you could create a [custom ContextProcessor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext), `ContextProcessors`

> take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context

A custom ContextProcessor in your case could look like this:

```py
def footer_data(request):
    return {'phone_number': 'xyz', ...}
```

Then append it to your settings.py so it is actually being used:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'myapp.my_context_processors.footer_data',
                ...
```

And in your templates you can access these variables simply with `{{ phone_numer }}`.